# Why is this variable in a class using inheritance not set?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, session-variables

I have created a class `validation` which takes users input and stores it in a class property called `user_data` and I have used a `foreach` loop to identify a empty field and if the empty field is found then I set a session variable to show an error to users in login page using `isset()` function.

And then I have used the power of inheritance and created some child classes which validates users inputs.

The problem here is that the `$errors` variable in class `validation`
and
the class `password_validate extends validation` where I used a session variable `$_SESSION['inval rep password']`, is not getting set.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

```
<?php 
session_start();
class validation{
    public $user_data; #storing users data
    public $errors; #storing errors that occurs

    #this function takes users data as an associative array and store it in class $user_data property
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->user_data = $data;
        
        #searching for any empty user inputs
        foreach($this->user_data as $key => $value){
            if(empty($value)){
                #using session variables to display errors to users
                $_SESSION["$key"."_empty"] = "set";
                #storing the errors in $errors property of this class
                $this->errors[] = "empty $key"; 
            }else{
                unset($_SESSION["$key"."_empty"]);
            }
        }
        #using session variables to hold data in the text-box
        foreach($this->user_data as $key => $value){
            $_SESSION["$key" . "_value"] = $value;
        }
    }
}  

#real problem starts from here, the errors are not storing  
class email_validate extends validation{
    function __construct(){
        if(!filter_var($this->user_data['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $this->errors[] = "inval email";
            $_SESSION['inval email'] = 'set';
        }else{
            unset($_SESSION['inval email']);
        }
    }
}
class password_validate extends validation{
    function __construct(){
        if(strlen($this->user_data['password']) < 6){
            $this->errors[] = "inval password";
            $_SESSION['inval password'] = 'set';
        }else{
            unset($_SESSION['inval password']);
        }
    }
}
#here is an other problem in this class
class repeat_password_validate extends validation{
    function __construct(){
        if($this->user_data['password'] !== $this->user_data['reppassword']){
            $this->errors[] = "inval repeat password";
            #this session is not getting set
            $_SESSION['inval rep password'] = 'set';
        }else{
            unset($_SESSION['inval rep password']);
        }
    }
}



$data = array("email" => "{$_POST['email']}", "password" => "{$_POST['password']}", "reppassword" => "{$_POST['reppassword']}");
$validation = new validation($data);

#executing validation
$email = new email_validate();
$password = new password_validate();
$repeated_password = new repeat_password_validate();
       

echo "<pre>";
print_r($validation->errors);
?>
```

Comment: The subclass constructors have to call the `validation` constructor.

Comment: `$email`, `$password`, and `$validation` are completely separate objects. So `$validation->errors` won't contain the errors found by `$email` or `$password`.

Comment: This isn't really an appropriate use of subclassing.

Comment: Can I ask, are you trying "to use OOP to solve a problem" or are you trying "to just learn OOP concepts"? If you are doing the latter, I'd recommend avoiding some additional abstractions such as sessions, databases and even HTML/HTTP for a bit, just to get an idea of how things work in an OOP context. Once you've got inheritance, visibility, etc. down, then start adding those back in.

Comment: What is the point of inheritance in that example? You should first understand what inheritance is and why it is useful as well as when to use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need this now, but I can suggest a solution. Try using this code.

```
<?php 
session_start();
class validation{
    public $user_data; #storing users data
    public $errors; #storing errors that occurs

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->user_data = $data;
        
        foreach($this->user_data as $key => $value){
            if(empty($value)){
                #using session variables to display errors to users
                $_SESSION["$key"."_empty"] = "set";
                #storing the errors in $errors property of this class
                $this->errors[] = "empty $key"; 
            }else{
                unset($_SESSION["$key"."_empty"]);
            }
        }
        #using session variables to hold data in the text-box
        foreach($this->user_data as $key => $value){
            $_SESSION["$key" . "_value"] = $value;
        }

        if ($this->email_validate() && $this->password_validate() && $this->repeat_password_validate()) {
            echo "Welcome!";
        } else {
            print_r($this->errors);
        }
    }

    private function email_validate() {
        if (!filter_var($this->user_data['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $this->errors[] = 'inval email';
            $_SESSION['inval email'] = 'set';
        } else {
            unset($_SESSION['inval email']);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private function password_validate() {
        if (strlen($this->user_data['password']) < 6) {
            $this->errors[] = 'inval password';
            $_SESSION['inval password'] = 'set';
        } else {
            unset($_SESSION['inval password']);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private function repeat_password_validate() {
        if ($this->user_data['reppassword'] !== $this->user_data['password']) {
            $this->errors[] = 'inval repeat password';
            $_SESSION['inval rep password'] = 'set';
        } else {
            unset($_SESSION['inval rep password']);
            return true;
        }
    }
}  





$data = array("email" => "{$_POST['email']}", "password" => "{$_POST['password']}", "reppassword" => "{$_POST['reppassword']}");
$validation = new validation($data);


?>
```

If you are working with classes, you can create one class and then create methods in it and call them in the same class. Try not creating many classes in one php file. Here I am creating email_validate(), password_validate() and repeat_password_validate() methods in validation() class. Then I am checking if all inputs are right, if so the methods will return true. Then in __construct() class I am checking if all methods returned true. If so, it means that there are no errors, else I am printing the errors.